# R Warning 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Tags: r

Using R 4.1.3 I observe:

```
var <- 0
> if(is.data.frame(var) || is.vector(var)) var <- as.matrix(var)
> is.null(var) || (!is.matrix(var) && var == 0) || (dim(var)==c(1,1) && var[1,1]==0)
[1] TRUE
```

However, with R 4.2.1 I observe the warning on this same code

```
> var <- 0
> if(is.data.frame(var) || is.vector(var)) var <- as.matrix(var)
> is.null(var) || (!is.matrix(var) && var == 0) || (dim(var)==c(1,1) && var[1,1]==0)
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
In dim(var) == c(1, 1) && var[1, 1] == 0 :
  'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

Having a hard time finding the root cause here. Any thoughts on a reason this occurs now and a good fix?

Comment: Try `print(dim(var))`. When `var` is a matrix, `dim(var)` will have length 2.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`dim(var) == c(1,1)` gives two `TRUE`. See **R** News below. Possible replacements are

```
identical(dim(var), c(1L, 1L))
all(dim(var) == c(1,1))
```

Previously we were told that `&&` and `||` are safe to use in `if ()` as they silently return a single TRUE or FALSE. But now it will warn you. This actually makes it easier to detect bugs, so I am happy with this change.

Unfortunately, this change has affected a few **R** packages (see for example: [Package ceases to work due to "if" error: condition has length > 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73100875/4891738)). As a result, the code that used to work smoothly suddenly throws warnings or even errors.

[image: change]

Comment: I think the code that used that construction didn't actually work.  The author probably intended one of your replacements, but instead `if()` only looked at the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in the same issue. I fixed my problem using a simple & rather than a double.

From this

```
filter(data, n > 1 && !!sym(group) %in% category_to_merge)
```

to this

```
filter(data, n > 1 & !!sym(group) %in% category_to_merge)
```