# is there a solution for Error in &&: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)

Tags: warnings

R Warning: Error in &&: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Warning: Error in ||: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

I am having this warnings in R. Any one can help me to solve the problem please!

I am a beginner working on Interactive R package with an intuitive Shiny-based graphical interface for alternative splicing analyses called PSICHOMICS.

Comment: This answer may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72848495/3225258