# R: choiceRT_ddm() function - Error in is.null(data) || is.na(data)

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to use a drift-diffusion model in R but I get a strange error message when I try running it:

```
Error in is.null(data) || is.na(data) : 'length = 162000' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

I already read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72848442/r-warning-lengthx-2-1-in-coercion-to-logical1) that it might be caused by an update that made logical operators && and || in if() statements produce warnings which in turn prevent the function from running smoothly. The thing is I still don't know what I could do to make the choiceRT_ddm() function work. There are no NAs in my df, so that can't be an issue here.

I wrote an example snippet that's also causing the error:

```
install.packages("hBayesDM")
library(hBayesDM)

# create random IDs for 30 subjects, 1800 trials for each one
subjID <- rep(1:30, each = 1800)

# create a vector with random choices (either 1 or 2)
choice <- sample(1:2, size = 1800 * 30, replace = TRUE)

# create a vector of random RTs (in seconds)
RT <- runif(1800 * 30, min = 0, max = 2)

# put all into 1 df
dummy_df <- data.frame(subjID, choice, RT)

# fit the drift-diffusion model:
dmm_fit <- choiceRT_ddm(data = dummy_df, 
                    niter = 2000, 
                    nwarmup = 1000, 
                    nchain = 4, 
                    ncore = 4)
```

Thanks in advance for any hints or ideas on how to deal with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the package, which has already been [reported](https://github.com/CCS-Lab/hBayesDM/issues/153). As the package maintainer does not seem to be particularly responsive, if you need the package, you can either install R 4.1, where this check would have passed. Or you can clone the package, fix the problematic check and then build the package yourself.

The bug stems from the fact that given a data frame, `is.na()` returns a matrix indicating for each element of the data frame if it is `NA`. However, `if()` works only with scalar values. Also, `&&` and `||` are meant to only be used with scalars. In earlier versions, when an input was non-scalar, R would make them scalar by taking only the first value of an input vector. But using non-scalars with these functions is almost always unintentional, and indicative of not actually testing what was intended to be tested. Thus, newer version fail on non-scalar inputs to `if()`, `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Ah okay, that's a bummer. Thanks for your detailed explanation though, now I get what's actually happening under the hood! Btw, for some reason I can only award the bounty in 21 hours, pls remind me to do so if I forget!