# ‘length(x) = 15041 > 1’ dans la coercion to ‘logical(1)’ : What can I do?

Tags: r, if-statement

I get this error message when trying to create a function:

```
assign_section <- function(variable_name) {
  # Create an empty list to store section matches
  sections <- character(0)

  # Check for patterns and add sections to the list
  if (grepl("^CY", variable_info$Variable_Name) && variable_info$Year == 2017) {
    sections <- c("Section 1")
  }
  if (grepl("HOD", variable_name)) {
    sections <- "Section 2"
  }
  if (grepl("WR", variable_name)) {
    sections <- "Section 3"
  }

final_section <- paste(sections, collapse = ", ")

return(final_section)
```

I'm a beginner with R. I understood that an if statement should have a length of 1 (either TRUE, or FALSE). But the error I get is the following:

1: In grepl("^CY", variable_info$Variable_Name) && variable_info$Year ==  ... :
‘length(x) = 15041 > 1’ in coercion to ‘logical(1)’

15041 is the number of rows I have. I'm asking R to look for all observations of variable_info with a Variable_Name starting with CY and a Year variable equal to 2017. I know there are some of them which is why it puzzles me. Can someone enlighten me please? :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Warning 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72848442/r-warning-lengthx-2-1-in-coercion-to-logical1)

Comment: Please add your dataset to this issue or do a reprex. 
1. reprex: copy your entire code and then run `reprex::reprex(venue = "r")`. Then Ctrl+V in your SO issue above.
2. Copy your data: You can use `datapasta::tribble_format(my_df)` which will convert and store your data in a tribble to your clipboard. Then, you can simply paste it to your SO issue above.

Answer (score 1):

`grepl("^CY", variable_info$Variable_Name)` returns a vector of 15041 `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but `if` conditions now only accept a single logical value (this used to generate a warning, it generates an error in most recent versions of R like yours). `all()` or `any()` might be helpful here.

But your code looks like it doesn't do what you want anyway since `sections` will only return either "Section 1", "Section 2" or "Section 3" (or an empty vector if none of the `if` conditions are true) and not a list with these 3 components.