# Why am I having issues plotting LAS with grDevices::terrain.colors()?

Tags: r, rgl, lidar, lidr

I'm trying to share a script amongst my colleagues, it involves creating a few small point cloud plots using lidR package. On my personal machine, I'm not having any issues, but my colleagues are all having issues and so is my remote desktop.

The plotting code essentially looks like this:

```
lidR::plot(las,size=5,pal=grDevices::terrain.colors(30),axis=TRUE)
```

The error everyone is getting (which I also receive, but on my computer, it displays the plots and shows this only as a warning):

```
Error in is.character(pal) && pal == "auto" : 'length = 30' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

I would like to manually select the colours displayed in the RGL window. How can I overcome this issue?

I've tried working with `RColorBrewer` along with manually inputting the colours, but I kept getting this error.

Comment: [warning vs error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72848442/r-warning-lengthx-2-1-in-coercion-to-logical1) may relate to your R version being older than your colleagues,  while the `pal` condition is found [&& pal == "auto"](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/blob/master/R/plot.R) line 290. Haven't found the subsequent `if()` that the first warning vs errors suggested (though tendency in R development is for warnings to become errors). And this may be something that pkg maintainer wants to hear about if akin to [issues 702](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/issues/702).Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a bug in the `lidR` code.  You are passing it the palette you want to use, and it is using a bad test to see if you requested `"auto"`.

Comment: You have something of an `x/y` question here. @jrr answer below, clears the warning/error, and should do so irrespective of R version, and you should accept it for the first `x` part. The `y` part of your question, `but our group wants to use a special group of selected colors, from the many available in the palettes` is a different question and should be asked separately. Hence the `x/y` designation.

Comment: The bug has been fixed on Github.  It should appear on CRAN with the next release, or you can install the development version directly from Github.

Comment: As @user2554330 says, you and your team should update to development version,  as I've done now for the second time today. I didn't have the wit to see what change to line 290 would solve, but your question pointed to it, and dmurdoch (`rgl` developer) solved. Quite an extraordinary first question process, keep up the good work (questioning). And now ask the `but we only want to use certain colors...` question. that I think you can get to, after update, with `grDevices::terrain.colors(30)[c(1, 6, 18, 22, 28)]`, (or whichever you've selected...), seems to work, could be wrong, as ever.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lidR::plot(las,size=5,pal=grDevices::terrain.colors, axis=TRUE)`